How to understand the different address spaces in ARM64 architecture?
The ARM architecture ref manual says an ARM processor (PE) can have multiple address spaces.
The typical two are Secure and Non-Secure address spaces.
If the realm feature (FEAT-RME) is implemented, there will be two more address spaces: Root and Realm address spaces.
My question is, how to understand these 4 address spaces?

Do they occupy 4 separate sub-ranges within the same single PE's physical space, which means they can't have the same address values.

Or they are totally irrelevant and the same address values can exist in each of them.


From the ARM MPAM spec, I found below word:

Arm recommends  that the numerical base addresses of the MPAM feature
pages in different address spaces be sufficiently different  that the
numerical address ranges do not overlap.

Feature pages are just a memory range containing a set of registers. The above sentence makes me believe 1) should be true, because if the different address spaces are irrelevant, we don't need to care about overlapping.
